# Confusion Over Traceback and Exiting

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.2

I haven't used Python in awhile updated to 3.2 from 3.1. My previous method of exiting Pygame programs is in the code below. Now I'm receiving a Traceback message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\Nero\gogo.py", line 24, in <module>
   terminate()
  File "C:\Python32\Nero\gogo.py", line 18, in terminate
   sys.exit()
SystemExit
```

Now I don't remember Traceback, but from what I can gather it's where the errors end up. This didn't produce errors in the past. I tried using exit() instead of sys.exit() but it requests confirmation to terminate the program and closes the shell as well (neither of which I want to occur). I've done some Google searching and found a variety of similar inquiries, but I'm still not sure the best way to understand this error and go about resolving it? The program still functions normally. I just isolated the relevant parts as the error remains the same in the larger program.

My code:

```
import random,math,sys,os
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'
pygame.init() #Initializing Pygame

screen=pygame.display.set_mode((500,500) ,0,0)
pygame.display.set_caption("Boo!")
pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
fps=40

#Functions:

def terminate():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
           if event.type == QUIT:
               sys.exit()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try replacing the `sys.exit()` in the last line you quoted with `terminate()`.

Comment: Are you launching this script from a shell, or double-clicking it in windows GUI?

Comment: Launching from shell. Sys.exit replaced with terminate() doesn't seem to have changed anything, unfortunately. I'm running a from shell.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this on Win7 w/ python 3.2 32bit and pygame 1.9.2a0 and I don't have that result.

What you are seeing is not really a genuine "error", but rather the `SystemExit` exception that is raised by calling `sys.exit()`. If you [refer to the docs](http://docs.python.org/release/3.2.2/library/sys.html#sys.exit), you will see that all the call does is raise the exception. If nothing else handles it, then it causes the main thread to terminate. This is supposed to be quiet (no stack trace as you are seeing). Unfortunately, I cannot give you an answer as to WHY you are seeing this stack trace.

If you are launching your script from the GUI, you should try created a `.pyw` extension version of the script to prevent a shell window from opening along with your GUI window. Maybe that might make a different in preventing you from seeing output?

Also, make sure you are actually calling your own `terminate()` method in your while loop as opposed to `sys.exit` directly.

Comment: I seem to have been calling terminate() and the sys.exit must have been incorrectly posted when I was trying various things to remove the error. I tried running it as a .pyw and nothing changed. It doesn't bother me as long as it's not a genuine problem in the program, but if I can figure out how to remove it, I'll update here.

Thanks